# Could anyone please suggest me MATHEMATICA code to solve Fractional-Order Time Delay Differential System?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

We are familiar that the Predictor-Corrector Algorithm is applied to solve the Fractional-Order Differential systems. I need to solve the following Fractional Order Delay Differential System. Please share any MATHEMATICA Code  for the following Fractional Order Delay Differential System:

```
D^α x[t] == z[t] + (y[t - τ] - a)*x[t];
D^α y[t] == 1 - b*y[t] - (x[t - τ])^2;
D^α z[t] == -x[t - τ] - c*z[t];
```

Where,

```
 a = 3; b = 0.1; c = 1, τ = 0.35 , and 
x[0] = 0.1; y[0] = 4; z[0] = 0.5 and α = 0.90.
```

Comment: vicky, you are aware that what you posted is not Mathematica code. Can you edit your question to make this code valid?

Comment: For the time delay problem we need to define `x[t], y[t], z[t]` for $t<0$ as well.

Comment: @AlexTrounev yes here i have mentioned those conditions too. Considered fractional order delay differential system,                              
 $\begin{eqnarray*}
D^{\alpha} x(t)&=&z+(y (t - \tau) - a)x\\
 D^{\alpha} y (t) &=& 1 - b y - (x (t -  \tau))^2\\
 D^{\alpha} z (t) &= &-x (t -  \tau) - c z.\\
 \end{eqnarray*}$

Where, $ a = 3,~ b =0.1,~ c = 1,~ \tau = 0.35 $, and $x(0) = 0.1, ~y(0) =4,~ z(0) = 0.5$  and $\alpha = 0.90.$ and for, $t<0,~ x(t)=0.1, ~y(t)=4,~ z(t)=0.5$

Comment: I found some Mathematica code in this forum but all those code use NDSolve built-in function. So dear all if possible please share me any link that contains code which applies numerical analysis to solve a fractional order delay differential system or even an integer order delay differential system is fine.

Comment: @vicky Is time interval up to infinity or limited? Please, pay attention that here is Mathematica forum, not Python. So function notation is `f[t]` not `f(t )` :)

Comment: @AlexTrounev yes time interval is finite. For example time can be considered till 2000

Comment: @vicky Why interval is required to be so large? There are several definitions of the fractional derivatives by Caputo, Riemann-Liouville, Atangana–Baleanu. What $D^{\alpha}$ means in your code?

Comment: @AlexTrounev I planned to study the chaotic nature of the above fractional order delay system so the interval should be at least 500 because chaos exist at large time. I adopt Caputo derivative.

Comment: @AlexTrounev In Mathematica I have written code for Predictor-Corrector Algorithm, which works good for a fractional order differential system but i am not able to edit that code for a delay system. Could you please edit my code so that it could work for a delay system.

Comment: @vicky Maybe, I can, but where is this code?

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2182596).

Comment: @AlexTrounev  I am waiting for your code so could you please post the code.

Comment: @vicky Ah, sorry! See my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no theorem for the fractional delay system like for the fractional system discussed in the paper [Analysis of Fractional Differential Equations](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Analysis-of-Fractional-Differential-Equations-Diethelm-Ford/cac7c06a93524b8abfec424508af694e95e0c843) and used to solve it with using the predictor-corrector method in this [paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20020024453/downloads/20020024453.pdf). But we can suggest that we can use this method at least for $0\le t \le \tau $, since functions $x(t-\tau),y(t-\tau)$ are given as initial condition. On this step we compute `x[t],y[t],z[t]`, and hence we can make next step on  $\tau \le t \le 2\tau $. Repeating this step we can solve problem. But final code very slow, and numerical solution slightly differ from that we can get with `NDSolve` for $\alpha=1$ (see code below and pictures after)

```
a1 = 3; b1 = 0.1; 
c1 = 1; 
f[t_, x_, y_, z_] := x*(y - a1) + z; 
g[t_, x_, y_, z_] := -(b1*y) - x^2 + 1; 
d[t_, x_, y_, z_] := -(c1*z) - x; 
\[Alpha] =1; 
h = 0.01; 
x0 = 0.1; 
y0 = 4; 
z0 = 0.5; tau = 0.15; nn = Round[tau/h]; n = 40 nn; Do[x[i] = x0; y[i] = y0; z[i] = z0, {i, -nn, 0}]; 
For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, b[k] = k^\[Alpha] - (k - 1)^\[Alpha]; a[k] = -(2*k^(\[Alpha] + 1)) + (k - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) + (k + 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1); ]; 
Do[Do[x1[i] = x[i - nn]; y1[i] = y[i - nn]; , {i, 0, s*nn}]; For[j = 1, j <= s*nn, j++, p[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*Sum[b[j - A]*f[A*h, x[A], y[A], z[A]], {A, 0, j - 1}])/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 1] + x[0]; 
     l[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*Sum[b[j - B]*g[B*h, x1[B], y[B], z[B]], {B, 0, j - 1}])/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 1] + y[0]; r[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*Sum[b[j - C]*d[C*h, x1[C], y[C], z[C]], {C, 0, j - 1}])/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 1] + z[0]; 
     x[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*(Sum[a[j - K]*f[h*K, x[K], y1[K], z[K]], {K, 1, j - 1}] + f[h*j, p[j], l[j], r[j]] + ((j - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) - (-\[Alpha] + j - 1)*j^\[Alpha])*f[0, x[0], y[0], z[0]]))/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 2] + x[0]; 
     y[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*(Sum[a[j - F]*g[F*h, x1[F], y[F], z[F]], {F, 1, j - 1}] + g[h*j, p[j], l[j], r[j]] + ((j - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) - (-\[Alpha] + j - 1)*j^\[Alpha])*g[0, x[0], y[0], z[0]]))/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 2] + y[0]; 
     z[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*(Sum[a[j - G]*d[G*h, x1[G], y[G], z[G]], {G, 1, j - 1}] + d[h*j, p[j], l[j], r[j]] + ((j - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) - (-\[Alpha] + j - 1)*j^\[Alpha])*d[0, x[0], y[0], z[0]]))/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 2] + z[0]; ]; , 
  {s, 1, 40}]
lst1 = Table[{x[j], y[j], z[j]}, {j, n}]; lst = 
 Table[{x[j], y[j], z[j]}, {j, 10, n, 10}]; lst2 = 
 Table[{x[j], y[j]}, {j, 10, n, 10}];
```

Now we can compare this solution (red points) with `NDSolve[]` solution (solid lines)

```
Clear[x, y, z];

sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == f[t, x[t], y[t - tau], z[t]], 
    y'[t] == g[t, x[t - tau], y[t], z[t]], 
    z'[t] == d[t, x[t - tau], y[t], z[t]], x[t /; t <= 0] == 0.1, 
    y[t /; t <= 0] == 4, z[t /; t <= 0] == 0.5}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 
    40}];

{Show[ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, .0, 6}, 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], ListPointPlot3D[lst1, PlotStyle -> Red]], 
 Show[ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, .0, 6}, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {x, y}], 
  ListPlot[lst2, PlotStyle -> Red]]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

We can improve this code and make it running faster but it is not so precise algorithm with of $h^2$ error. When we compare with `NDSolve` we need to decries `h` down to .0025  for `t=15`, but solutions are differ since it unstable for this set of parameters

```
a1 = 3; b1 = 0.1; 
c1 = 1; 
f[t_, x_, y_, z_] := x*(y - a1) + z; 
g[t_, x_, y_, z_] := -(b1*y) - x^2 + 1; 
d[t_, x_, y_, z_] := -(c1*z) - x; 
\[Alpha] =1; 
h = 0.0025; 
x0 = .1; 
y0 =4; 
z0 =1/2; tau = 0.15; nn = Round[tau/h]; smax = Round[15/tau];n=nn*smax; 
Do[x[i] = x0; y[i] = y0; z[i] = z0, {i, -nn, 0}]; 
For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, b[k] = k^\[Alpha] - (k - 1)^\[Alpha]; a[k] = -(2*k^(\[Alpha] + 1)) + (k - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) + (k + 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1); ]; 
Do[Do[x1[i] = x[i - nn]; y1[i] = y[i - nn]; , {i, 0, s*nn}]; For[j = (s-1)*nn+1, j <= s*nn, j++, p[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*Sum[b[j - A]*f[A*h, x[A], y[A], z[A]], {A, 0, j - 1}])/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 1] + x[0]; 
     l[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*Sum[b[j - B]*g[B*h, x1[B], y[B], z[B]], {B, 0, j - 1}])/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 1] + y[0]; r[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*Sum[b[j - C]*d[C*h, x1[C], y[C], z[C]], {C, 0, j - 1}])/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 1] + z[0]; 
     x[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*(Sum[a[j - K]*f[h*K, x[K], y1[K], z[K]], {K, 1, j - 1}] + f[h*j, p[j], l[j], r[j]] + ((j - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) - (-\[Alpha] + j - 1)*j^\[Alpha])*f[0, x[0], y[0], z[0]]))/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 2] + x[0]; 
     y[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*(Sum[a[j - F]*g[F*h, x1[F], y[F], z[F]], {F, 1, j - 1}] + g[h*j, p[j], l[j], r[j]] + ((j - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) - (-\[Alpha] + j - 1)*j^\[Alpha])*g[0, x[0], y[0], z[0]]))/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 2] + y[0]; 
     z[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*(Sum[a[j - G]*d[G*h, x1[G], y[G], z[G]], {G, 1, j - 1}] + d[h*j, p[j], l[j], r[j]] + ((j - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) - (-\[Alpha] + j - 1)*j^\[Alpha])*d[0, x[0], y[0], z[0]]))/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 2] + z[0]; ]; , 
  {s, 1, smax}]

lst1 = Table[{x[j], y[j], z[j]}, {j, n}]; lst = 
 Table[{x[j], y[j], z[j]}, {j, 10, n, 10}]; lst2 = 
 Table[{x[j], y[j]}, {j, n}];

Clear[x, y, z];

sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == f[t, x[t], y[t - tau], z[t]], 
    y'[t] == g[t, x[t - tau], y[t], z[t]], 
    z'[t] == d[t, x[t - tau], y[t], z[t]], x[t /; t <= 0] == 0.1, 
    y[t /; t <= 0] == 4, z[t /; t <= 0] == 0.5}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 15}];

{Show[ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, .0, 15}, 
   AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], ListPointPlot3D[lst1, PlotStyle -> Red]], 
 Show[ListPlot[lst2, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   FrameLabel -> {x, y}, AspectRatio -> 1], 
  ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, .0, 15}]]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: The above code works good for a three dimensional system but in the case of four dimensional system.   I get the following error message ```General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.```  Could anyone please give suggestions to solve this issue

Comment: @vicky We can give you suggestion if you show your system.

Comment: Here is my system  $D^\alpha x[t]=x[t]*(y[t-\tau]-a1)+(m_1 * w[t])+z[t];\\
  D^\alpha y[t]= - b1*y[t]+(m_2 * w[t])-x[t-\tau]^2+1;\\
  D^\alpha z[t] = -x[t - \tau] - c1*z[t]+(m_3 * w[t]);\\
   D^\alpha w[t] = -x[t]*y[t]*z[t].\\$    $\alpha=0.93; a1 = 2.1; b1 = 0.01;
c1 = 2.6;
m_1 = 8.4;
m_2 = 6.4;
m_3= 2.2$ and for $t\leq 0,x[t] = 2;y[t] = 0;z[t] = -0.2;w[t] = 0.4.$

Comment: @vicky Can you start a new topic with explanation of  this system and with code you run?

Comment: In the above four dimensional system when $\tau=0.10$ and $n=4500$(smax=300 in the above code) I get error message

Comment: Sure will do it

Comment: Here I share my new question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240347/overflow-during-computation