# Numerical solution for a non-linear Fractional Differential Equation (FDE)

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, finite-difference-method

As shown below, a neat explicit expression is obtained for F=2, however
an exact solution is not present for  1< F < 2.

How do we obtain numerical values for F = 1.5 (for instance)?

There have been suggestions of approximate methods (Adomian decomposition method (ADM), the variational iteration method (VIM)), these could involve time-consuming data crunching, and not sure if such techniques are already utilized in Mathematica.

The exact solution for the F=2 case does allow the testing of these possible alternative methods, hopefully one where rapid convergence is noted.
An algorithm based on the Adomian decomposition method and the Padé approximants technique for nonlinear fractional differential equations with initial or boundary conditions is described [here](https://www.swmath.org/software/10220), but I am unable to access this code.

```
F = 2;


sol = DSolve[{CaputoD[y[x], {x, F}] - 9/4 Sqrt[y[x]] - y[x] == 0, 
   y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 2}, y[x], x]


Table[{x, Evaluate[y[x] /. sol[[1]]]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}]

Plot[Evaluate[y[x]  . sol[[1]]], {x, 0, 1}]

> (* {{y[x] ->     1/16 E^(-2 x) (E^x + 54 E^(2 x) + 81 E^(3 x) - 
>       12 Sqrt[E^(3 x) (1 + 9 E^x)^2])}} *)
> 
> (* {{0., 1.}, {0.1, 1.21698}, {0.2, 1.47099}, {0.3, 1.76705}, {0.4, 
>   2.11074}, {0.5, 2.50829}, {0.6, 2.96662}, {0.7, 3.49344}, {0.8, 
>   4.09733}, {0.9, 4.78782}, {1., 5.57553}} *)
```

[image]

Comment: ``NDSolve`` [can't deal with](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271689/75628) ``CaputoD`` yet ...

Comment: Fractional differential equation is a relatively new topic (according to my limited knowledge). Are you aware of any standard method for numerically solving the problem? If the answer is yes, mentioning it in the question or even changing the question to something like "how to implement ×× method for solving this FDE" will make the question more attractive.

Comment: "but I am unable to access this code" - you didn't look for it hard enough, I would say: https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/dn82gkvf4f/1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several numerical methods to solve fractional DE and PDE, including predictor-corrector method described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239669/could-anyone-please-suggest-me-mathematica-code-to-solve-fractional-order-time-d), and wavelets method discussed in our [paper](https://advancesindifferenceequations.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13662-021-03262-7) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221609/solver-for-covid-19-epidemic-model-with-the-caputo-fractional-derivatives). First we solve this problem for $1\le F\le 2$ with Haar wavelets. Note, that in this case we have the second order problem, and it is why we need two boundary conditions. In a case $F=2$ we have  `CaputoD[y[x], {x, F}]=D[y[x], {x, 2}]`, therefore problem turns to second order ODE with known solution. This solution we gonna use as a test. With Haar wavelets we can compute `CaputoD[y[x], {x, q}]` as follows

```
h[x_, k_, m_] := 
  WaveletPsi[HaarWavelet[], m x - k, WorkingPrecision -> Infinity];

p[x_, k_, m_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(1 + k - m*x)/m, k >= 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*x < 0 && 
           1/m + k/m - x >= 0 && m > 0}, {(-k + m*x)/m, 
    k >= 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*x >= 0 && 
           k/m - x < 0 && 1/m + k/m - x >= 0 && m > 0}}, 0];
h1[x_] := WaveletPhi[HaarWavelet[], x, WorkingPrecision -> Infinity];

p1[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x > 1}}, x];

pc[t_, k_, m_, q_] := 
 Piecewise[{{-(t^(1 - q)/(-1 + q)), k == 0 && 1/m - 2*t >= 0 && 
          m > 0 && t > 0 && 1/m - t >= 0}, 
      {-((m^(-1 + q)*(1/(-k + m*t))^(-1 + q))/(-1 + q)), 
        k > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t > 0 && k/m - t < 0 && m > 0 && 
          1/m + k/m - t > 0}, 
      {(-t^q + 2*m*t^(1 + q) - m*t*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q)/
          (t^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q*(m*(-1 + q))), 
        k == 0 && m > 0 && 1/m - 2*t < 0 && 1/m - t >= 0}, 
      {(1/(-1 + q))*((2^(-1 + q)*m^(-1 + 2*q)*(-(-(k/m) + t)^q - 
                   2*k*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 2*m*t*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 
                   2*k*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q - 
           2*m*t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
                       q))/((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q), 
        k > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t == 0 && m > 0 && 
          1/m + k/m - t > 0}, 
      {-((1/(-1 + q))*((2^(-1 + q)*m^(-1 + 2*q)*
                   (-2*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
               q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
                          q - 2*k*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q*
                        ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q + 
                      
             2*m*t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*
                             (k - m*t))^q + (-((1 + k)/m) + t)^q*
                        ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q + 
                      
             2*k*(-((1 + k)/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
                          q - 2*m*t*(-((1 + k)/m) + t)^q*
                        ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
               q + (-(k/m) + t)^q*
                        ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q + 
                      
             2*k*(-(k/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^
               q - 
                      
             2*m*t*(-(k/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^
                          q - 2*k*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q*
                        ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q + 
                      
             2*m*t*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*
                             (1 + k - m*t))^
               q))/(((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q*
                   ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(1 + k - m*t))^q))), 
        k > 0 && m > 0 && 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t <= 0 && 
          1/m + k/m - t <= 0}, 
      {-((1/(2*m*(-1 + q)))*((2^q*m^(2*q)*t^q*(-(1/m) + t)^q*
                     (-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q - 
           2^(1 + q)*m^(1 + 2*q)*t^(1 + q)*
                     (-(1/m) + t)^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q - 
           2^(1 + q)*m^(2*q)*
                     t^q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^(2*q) + 
           2^(1 + q)*m^(1 + 2*q)*
                     t^(1 + q)*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^(2*q) + 
                   t^q*((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q - 2*m*t^(1 + q)*
                     ((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q + 
           2*m*t*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q*
                     ((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q)/(t^
            q*(-(1/(2*m)) + t)^q*
                   ((-1 + m*t)*(-1 + 2*m*t))^q))), 
        k == 0 && 1/m - 2*t < 0 && 1/m - t < 0 && m > 0}, 
      {(1/(-1 + q))*((2^(-1 + q)*m^(-1 + q)*((-m^q)*(-(k/m) + t)^q - 
                   2*k*m^q*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 
           2*m^(1 + q)*t*(-(k/m) + t)^q + 
                   2*k*m^q*(-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^q - 2*m^(1 + q)*t*
                     (-((1/2 + k)/m) + t)^
             q - ((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q*
                     (1/(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t))^q - 
                   2*k*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q*
                     (1/(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t))^q + 
                   2*m*t*((1 + 2*k - 2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^q*
                     (1/(-1 - 2*k + 2*m*t))^q))/((1 + 2*k - 
            2*m*t)*(k - m*t))^
               q), 1/m + (2*k)/m - 2*t < 0 && k > 0 && m > 0 && 
          1/m + k/m - t > 0}}, 0]

pc1[t_, q_] := Piecewise[{{-(t^(1 - q)/(-1 + q)), t <= 1}}, 
    -(((-1 + t)^q*t + t^q - t^(1 + q))/((-1 + t)^q*t^q*(-1 + q)))];
```

Here `p, p1` are integrals of `h,h1`, and `pc, pc1` are Caputo derivatives of `h, h1`. With these functions we can compute numerical solution for $0\le q\le 1$ by reducing order  FDE as

```
eqs={CaputoD[z[x],{x,q}] - 9/4 Sqrt[y[x]] - y[x] == 0, z[x]==y'[x],
   y[0] == 1, z[0] == 2}
```

Finally we define numerical functions `y[x],z[x]` and first derivatives `y1[x], z1[x]`, and compute `eqs` in collocation points `xcol`

```
J = 4; M = 2^J; dx = 1/(2*M); xl = Table[l dx, {l, 0, 2 M}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, 2 M + 1}]; 
z1[x_, q_] := 
 Sum[v[i, j] pc[x, i, 2^j, q], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
  v1 pc1[x, q]; 
z[x_] := 
 Sum[v[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
  v1 p1[x] + v0;
y1[x_] := 
 Sum[u[i, j] h[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
  u1 h1[x]; 
y[x_] := 
 Sum[u[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
  u1 p1[x] + u0;
varM = Join[{v0, v1, u0, u1}, 
  Flatten[Table[v[i, j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]], 
  Flatten[Table[u[i, j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]]; 
eq[q_] := 
 Flatten[Table[{1/Gamma[1 - q] z1[x, q] - 9/4 Sqrt[Abs[y[x]]] - y[x] ==
      0, y1[x] - z[x] == 0}, {x, xcol}]]; bc = {y[0] == 1, z[0] == 2};
```

The system of algebraic equations can be solved with `FindRoot` for several `q`

```
qlist = {99/100, 1/2, 1/3};

Do[
  eqM[i] = Join[eq[i], bc];
  solv[i] = 
   FindRoot[eqM[i], Table[{varM[[j]], 1/10}, {j, Length[varM]}], 
    MaxIterations -> 1000, WorkingPrecision -> 30];, {i, 
   qlist}]
```

Visualization together with test data

```
Do[lst[i] = 
   Table[{x , Evaluate[y[x] /. solv[i]]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}];, {i, qlist}]

test = {{0., 1.}, {0.1, 1.21698}, {0.2, 1.47099}, {0.3, 
    1.76705}, {0.4, 2.11074}, {0.5, 2.50829}, {0.6, 2.96662}, {0.7, 
    3.49344}, {0.8, 4.09733}, {0.9, 4.78782}, {1., 5.57553}};

Show[ListLinePlot[Table[lst[i], {i, qlist}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
     PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Table[Row[{"F = ", qlist[[i]] + 1}], {i, Length[qlist]}]], 
 ListPlot[test, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Predictor-corrector code is based on the pseudocode published in the end of [paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20020024453/downloads/20020024453.pdf)

```
g[t_, y_] := 9/4 Sqrt[y] + y;

\[Alpha] = 199./100;
h = 1./100;
y[0] = y0[0] = 1;
y0[1] = 2; n = 100;
For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, b[k] = k^\[Alpha] - (k - 1)^\[Alpha]; 
  a[k] = -(2*k^(\[Alpha] + 1)) + (k - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) + (k + 
       1)^(\[Alpha] + 1);];
For[j = 1, j <= n, j++, 
  p[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*Sum[b[j - A]*g[A*h, y[A]], {A, 0, j - 1}])/
      Gamma[\[Alpha] + 1] + y0[0] + j h y0[1];
   
   y[j] = (h^\[Alpha]*(Sum[a[j - f]*g[f*h, y[f]], {f, 1, j - 1}] + 
          g[h*j, p[
            j]] + ((j - 1)^(\[Alpha] + 1) - (-\[Alpha] + j - 1)*
              j^\[Alpha])*g[0, y[0]]))/Gamma[\[Alpha] + 2] + y0[0] + 
     j h y0[1];
   ;];
```

Visualization together with `test` data

```
lst = Table[{j h, y[j]}, {j, n}];
test = {{0., 1.}, {0.1, 1.21698}, {0.2, 1.47099}, {0.3, 
   1.76705}, {0.4, 2.11074}, {0.5, 2.50829}, {0.6, 2.96662}, {0.7, 
   3.49344}, {0.8, 4.09733}, {0.9, 4.78782}, {1., 5.57553}}; Show[
 ListLinePlot[lst], ListPlot[test, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Finally note, that solver proposed by xzczd is not so good compare to wavelets and predictor-corrector method and needs to be improved. Code is given by

```
F = 3/2; yfunc = 
 x |-> a + b x + 
   c x^2; ivp = {CaputoD[y[x], {x, F}] - 9/4 Sqrt[y[x]] - y[x] == 0 /. 
   x -> x0 + dx, y[x0] == y0, y'[x0] == dy0};
solrule = 
 Solve[ivp /. y -> yfunc, {a, b, 
   c}]; (Subtract @@@ ivp /. y -> yfunc /. # /. {x0 -> 0, y0 -> 1, 
      dy0 -> 2, dx -> 0.1, a -> 1, b -> 2} // N) & /@ solrule; cf = 
 Compile[{x0, y0, dy0, dx}, 
  Evaluate[{x0 + dx, yfunc[x0 + dx], yfunc'[x0 + dx], dx} /. 
    solrule[[-1]]]];

solver[x0_, y0_, dy0_, dx_, tend_] := 
 MapAt[List, 
    NestList[cf @@ # &, {x0, y0, dy0, dx}, 
       tend/dx // Round]\[Transpose] // Most, {1, All}] // Transpose //
   Interpolation
tend = 1;
nsol = solver[0, 1, 2, 0.01, tend]
nsol // ListPlot
```

In the picture below shown Figure 1 with wavelets method results, predictor-corrector method for `F=3/2` - dashed red line and `nsol` - doted line. We see that two methods are in a good agreement while `nsol` is out of range.
[image: Figure 3]

Updated code by xzczd is in a good agreement with Haar wavelets method and predictor-corrector method as well. Code

```
n = 16;
range = Range[0, n - 1];
coef = c /@ range;
poly[x_] = coef . x^range;
CGLGrid[xl_, xr_, n_Integer /; n > 1] := 
 1/2 (xl + xr + (xl - xr) Cos[(\[Pi] Range[0, n - 1])/(n - 1)])
grid = CGLGrid[0, 1, n];

F = 3/2;
{eq, ic} = {CaputoD[y[x], {x, F}] - 9/4 Sqrt[y[x]] - y[x] == 
    0, {y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 2}};

approx = eq /. y -> poly; // AbsoluteTiming
cguess = 1;
crule = FindRoot[
    Table[approx, {x, grid[[3 ;;]]}]~
     Join~(ic /. y -> poly), {#, cguess} & /@ coef]; // AbsoluteTiming


pseudo = 
 Plot[poly[x] /. crule // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Dashed]
```

In the picture below the dashed line is the numerical solution computed with xzczd code compare to wavelets (left) and predictor-corrector method (right):

[image: Figure 4]

Comment: Can you extend the solution range? For example and for general: $x\in \{a,b\}$ maybe for : $x\in \{-2,3\}$. Thanks for excellent answer. (+1)

Comment: Yes we can solve it on (a, b) using map (a, b)->(0,1) in a form $x=a+s (b-a)$ with $s\in \{0,1\}$ :)

Comment: Can you update the `code` of yours last findings on the comment? because for me it's dark magic.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk This answer is too long. Could you ask your question as a separate post?

Answer (score 11):

### Update 2: A general-purpose IVP solver for FDE

The following is a general-purpose implementation for the predictor-corrector method in [this paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20020024453/downloads/20020024453.pdf) linked by Alex:

```
BeginPackage["fdeivp`"];
fdesolve; fdesolvecore;
Begin["`private`"];
Clear[fdesolve, fdesolvecore];
Options[fdesolve] = {Compiled -> True};
fdesolve[α_, f_, y0_?NumericQ, rest__] := fdesolve[α, f, {y0}, rest]
fdesolve[α_, f_, y0_?VectorQ, rest__] /; Length@y0 != Ceiling@α := 
 fdesolve[α, f, {y0}, rest]
fdesolve[α_, f_, y0_, T_, n_Integer : 25, OptionsPattern[]] :=
 With[{size = Rest@Dimensions@y0},
  fdesolvecore[α, f, size, OptionValue@Compiled][y0, T, n]]
   
fdesolvecore[α_, f_, size_, tf : True | False] := 
  fdesolvecore[α, f, size, tf] = 
   With[{m = Ceiling[α], dim = 1 + Length@size}, 
    Hold@function[argu, with[{h = T/n,                 
               b = Table[If[k == 0, 0, k^α - (k - 1)^α], {k, 0, n}],                 
               a = Table[If[k == 0, 0, (k + 1)^(α + 1) - 
                             2 k^(α + 1) + (k - 1)^(α + 1)], {k, 0, n}]},
              module[{y = Table[0., {n + 1}, ##], p},
               y[0] = y0[0];                  
               Do[p = Sum[(j h)^k/k! y0[k], {k, 0, m - 1}] + 
                  h^α/Gamma[α + 1] Sum[b[j - k] f[k h, y[k]], {k, 0, j - 1}];   
                y[j] = Sum[(j h)^k/k! y0[k], {k, 0, m - 1}] + 
                  h^α/Gamma[α + 2] (f[j h, p] + ((j - 1)^(α + 1) - (j - 1 - α) j^α) f[
                    0, y[0]] + Sum[a[j - k] f[k h, y[k]], {k, j - 1}]),                
                {j, n}]; y]]] & @@ (List /@ size) /. (head : y | y0 | a | b)[i_] :> 
          head[[i + 1]] /. {module -> Module, with -> With} /. {function -> 
         If[tf, Compile, Function], 
        argu -> If[tf, {{y0, _Real, dim}, {T, _Real}, {n, _Integer}}, {y0, T, n}]} /. 
      Factorial[n_] :> Gamma[1 + n] // ReleaseHold];
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

With this package, OP's problem can be solved as follows:

```
order = 1.5; rhsfunc = {t, y} |-> 9/4 Sqrt[y] + y; iclst = {1, 2}; tend = 1;

sollst = fdesolve[order, rhsfunc, iclst, tend];
```

The output is a `List`, it can be visualized with e.g.

```
ListPlot[sollst, DataRange -> {0, tend}]
```

If you prefer a function relationship as the output, build a interpolating function with e.g.

```
solfunc = ListInterpolation[sollst, {0, tend}]
```

---

### Update

Though my old answer is wrong, I manage to think out a correct one.

The idea is again simple: given that *usually* the solution of differential equation can be approximated (**without Runge's phenomenon**) with n-th order polynomial whose coefficient is determined by function values at Chebyshev-Gauss-Lobatto grid (notice this is essentially the spirit of pseudospectral method), and `CaputoD` is capable of calculating derivative of polynomial, we assume the solution of the initial value problem (IVP) in the **whole** interval $[0,1]$ can be approximated by

$$y=c_0+c_1 x+…+c_{n-1} x^{n-1}$$

```
n = 16;
range = Range[0, n - 1];
coef = c /@ range;
poly[x_] = coef . x^range;
```

Then substitute it into the differential equation and i.c.s, and calculate the specific algebraic equations at Chebyshev-Gauss-Lobatto grid:

```
CGLGrid[xl_, xr_, n_Integer /; n > 1] := 
 1/2 (xl + xr + (xl - xr) Cos[(π Range[0, n - 1])/(n - 1)])
grid = CGLGrid[0, 1, n];

F = 3/2;
{eq, ic} = {CaputoD[y[x], {x, F}] - 9/4 Sqrt[y[x]] - y[x] == 0, 
            {y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 2}};

{approxeq, approxic} = {eq, ic} /. y -> poly; // AbsoluteTiming
cguess = 1;
crule = FindRoot[
    Table[approxeq, {x, grid[[3 ;;]]}]~Join~approxic, {#, cguess} & /@ 
     coef]; // AbsoluteTiming

pseudo = Plot[poly[x] /. crule // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}, 
     PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Now the solution is consistent with those shown by Alex.

BTW, the following is a compiled version of the predictor-corrector method shown in Alex's answer:

```
g[t_, y_] := 9/4 Sqrt[y] + y;

alexsolver = Hold@Compile[{{n, _Integer}, α}, Module[{
         h = 1./n,
         y = Table[0., {n + 1}],
         y0 = Table[0., {n + 1}],
         a = Table[0., {n + 1}],
         b = Table[0., {n + 1}],
         p = Table[0., {n + 1}], k, j},
        y[0] = y0[0] = 1;
        y0[1] = 2;
        For[k = 1, k <= n, k++, b[k] = k^α - (k - 1)^α;
         a[
           k] = -(2*k^(α + 1)) + (k - 1)^(α + 1) + (k + 1)^(α + 
              1);];
        For[j = 1, j <= n, j++, 
         p[j] = (h^α*Sum[b[j - A]*g[A*h, y[A]], {A, 0, j - 1}])/
            Gamma[α + 1] + y0[0] + j h y0[1];
         y[
           j] = (h^α*(Sum[a[j - f]*g[f*h, y[f]], {f, 1, j - 1}] + 
                g[h*j, p[j]] + ((j - 1)^(α + 1) - (-α + j - 1)*
                    j^α)*g[0, y[0]]))/Gamma[α + 2] + y0[0] + j h y0[1]];
        y], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
     DownValues@g /. (head : y | y0 | a | b | p)[i_] :> head[[i + 1]] // ReleaseHold;

n = 10^4; h = 1/n; F = 3/2; ylst = alexsolver[n, F]; // AbsoluteTiming

alexsol = ListInterpolation[ylst, {0, 1}];
pseudo~Show~ListLinePlot[alexsol, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]
```

[image]

---

### Old Incorrect Answer

**The following answer is wrong, because definition of `CaputoD` involves integration from `0` to `x`, so we can not approximate `CaputoD` only with function value in a small interval $[x_0,x_0+dx]$ (except for $x_0=0$).**

Since currently `NDSolve` cannot handle fractional differential equation, I'd like to add a primary but working home-made solution.

The idea is simple: given that *usually* the solution of differential equation can be approximated with piecewise polynomial (notice this is essentially the spirit of finite difference method (FDM)), and `CaputoD` is capable of calculating derivative of polynomial, we assume that the solution of the initial value problem (IVP) in a small interval $[x_0,x_0+dx]$ can be approximated by

$$y\approx a+bx+cx^2$$

```
yfunc = x |-> a + b x + c x^2;
```

Substitue this into the IVP and solve:

```
ivp = {CaputoD[y[x], {x, F}] - 9/4 Sqrt[y[x]] - y[x] == 0 /. x -> x0 + dx, 
   y[x0] == y0, y'[x0] == dy0};
solrule = Solve[ivp /. y -> yfunc, {a, b, c}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `Solve::nongen` There may be values of the parameters for which some or all solutions are not valid.

```
(* {0.0378036, Null} *)
```

Hmm… something improper seems to happen in `Solve`. Further check via `Dimensions@solrule` suggests 2 solutions are found, which is a bit counterinituive. I don't bother to looking into what happens in `Solve`, so I simply check the solutions numerically:

```
(Subtract @@@ ivp /. y -> yfunc /. # /. {x0 -> 0, y0 -> 1, dy0 -> 2, 
      dx -> 0.1, a -> 1, b -> 2} // N) & /@ solrule
(* {{-4.89298, 0., 0.}, {-4.44089*10^-16, 0., 0.}} *)
```

OK, seems that only the last solution is valid. Extract it, and substitute it into `yfunc`, we obtain the approximate solution at $x_0+dx$. Needless to say, the process can be done repeatively, so we can obtain the numeric solution in arbitrary interval. The programming is straightforward:

```
cf = Compile[{x0, y0, dy0, dx}, 
  Evaluate[{x0 + dx, yfunc[x0 + dx], yfunc'[x0 + dx], dx} /. solrule[[-1]]]]

solver[x0_, y0_, dy0_, dx_, tend_] := 
 MapAt[List, 
    NestList[cf @@ # &, {x0, y0, dy0, dx}, tend/dx // Round]\[Transpose] // Most, 
       {1, All}] // Transpose // Interpolation
```

Here, 4th syntax in document of `Interpolation` is used to take the derivative into account when building `InterpolatingFunction`.

Usage of `solver`:

```
tend = 1;      
nsol = solver[0, 1, 2, 0.1, tend]
nsol // ListPlot
```

[image]

I've used an undocumented syntax of `ListPlot` here. See [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163273/1871) for more info.

Finally let's check the convergency of this method:

```
With[{lst = 10.^-Range[5]}, 
 Table[solver[0, 1, 2, dx, tend], {dx, lst}] // 
  ListLinePlot[#, PlotLegends -> lst] &]
```

[image]

Um… not too bad (at least in my view). As mentioned in the beginning, this is merely a primary solution. Seeing it working, I'm satisfied enough.

Comment: Nice approach (+1). Note, we can test your algorithm for `CaputoD[y[x], {x, F}]  - y[x] == 0` with `F={1/2, 1}`. Also there are wavelets solution on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221609/solver-for-covid-19-epidemic-model-with-the-caputo-fractional-derivatives and predictor-corrector solution on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239669/could-anyone-please-suggest-me-mathematica-code-to-solve-fractional-order-time-d

Comment: I have compared 3 methods in my answer, and your method seems not so good.

Comment: @xzczd Yes correct about the residual error being insignificant (Trounev's method) , also issues with smaller F ( less than 1.5)  in your method where the simple series is taken, perhaps the coefficients to be used needs further examination. In any case both suggested answers are good steps forward.

Comment: @xzczd Do you mean predictor-corrector method? Actually it is not mine method, it taken from the NASA report published on https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20020024453/downloads/20020024453.pdf . Also I don't understand what do you try to compare with?

Comment: @xzczd You are not right, since we solve numerical equation, and not FDE himself. We only can compare numerical solution with some exact solution, for instance with solution at `F=2`. In this case predictor-corrector method gives relative error of about $5 \times10^{-6}$.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I add a new method that agrees with yours.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you very much! Now it should be (+2). :)

Answer (score 2):

Good reference is provided by  "A review of the Adomian decomposition method and its applications to fractional differential equations ", Commun.Frac.Calc.3 (2) (2012) 73-99

Note that the non-linear operator is taken to be semi-analytic, and  to simplify the computation we consider just the first four terms  starting with y0 which is set to 1, in this  code we identify  the Adomian polynomials by A_0, A_1, etc and an image of the code is attached below for easy viewing of Subscripted terms

```
ClearAll;
Jf[u_, v_, x_] := Gamma[v + 1]/Gamma[u + v + 1] x^(u + v)
Subscript[y, 0] = 1;
Subscript[A, 0] = 1;
Subscript[y, 1][u_, x_] := 2 x + 9/4 Jf[u, 0, x] + Jf[u, 0, x]
Subscript[A, 1][u_, x_] := Subscript[y, 1][u, x]/(
 2 Subscript[y, 0]^0.5)

Subscript[y, 2][u_, x_] := 17/4 Jf[u, 1, x] + (221/32)/Gamma[u + 1] Jf[u, u, x]

Subscript[A, 2][u_, x_] := Subscript[y, 2][u, x]/(2 Subscript[y, 0]^0.5) -  Subscript[y, 1][u, x]^2/(4 Subscript[y, 0]^(3/2))

Subscript[y, 3][u_,x_] := -(9/8) Jf[u, 2, x] + (17^2/(32*Gamma[u + 2]) - 117/(32*Gamma[u + 2])) Jf[u, 1 + u, x] + (3757/(256*Gamma[2 u + ]) - 1521/(512*Gamma[u + 2]^2)) Jf[
    u, 2 u, x]

Subscript[A, 3][u_, x_] := 
 Subscript[y, 3][u, x]/(2 Subscript[y, 0]^0.5) - 
  Subscript[y, 2][u, x]^2/(4 Subscript[y, 0]^(3/2)) - (
  Subscript[y, 1][u, x] Subscript[y, 2][u, x])/(
  2 Subscript[y, 0]^(3/2)) + (3 Subscript[y, 1][u, x]^2)/(
  8 Subscript[y, 0]^(5/2))

Subscript[y, 4][u_, x_] := 
 9/8 Jf[u, 3, x] + 
  1/16 ((-9*34)/(4*Gamma[u + 3]) - (18*17)/(4*Gamma[u + 2]) + (
     27*13)/(4*Gamma[u + 1])) Jf[u, u + 2, x]


Subscript[y, T][u_, x_] := 
 Subscript[y, 0] + Subscript[y, 1][u, x] + Subscript[y, 2][u, x] + 
  Subscript[y, 3][u, x]

Subscript[y, exact][x_] := 
 1/16 E^(-2 x) (E^x + 54 E^(2 x) + 81 E^(3 x) - 
    12 Sqrt[E^(3 x) (1 + 9 E^x)^2])


 Plot[{Subscript[y, T][1.25, x], Subscript[y, T][1.5, x], 
  Subscript[y, T][1.75, x], Subscript[y, T][2, x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> {1.25`, 1.5`, 1.75`, 2, Exact}]

Plot[Subscript[y, T][2, x] - Subscript[y, exact][x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", GridLines -> Automatic]

Table[{x, Subscript[y, T][2, x] - Subscript[y, exact][x]}, {x, 0, 1, 
   0.1}] // TableForm


 Plot[{Subscript[y, T][1.5, x], poly[x] /. crule // Evaluate}, {x, 0, 
  1}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> {Adomian, poly}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Comparison with results from one method suggested above]

[image: code as an image file]

Comment: `ClearAll;` doesn't have the effect in your mind. Please read the document of 
 it carefully.