# Numerical Solution for a Non-Linear Functional Fractional Differential Equation (FFDE)

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, finite-difference-method

I tried solve non-linear Functional-Fractional Differential Equation (FFDE) with this [method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271690/numerical-solution-for-a-non-linear-fractional-differential-equation-fde/271735?noredirect=1#comment736027_271735), but it works on only for range:  $x\in \{0,1\}$.

I what **extend** the solution range for example for general **a** and **b**.

```
a =-3;
b = 2;
DSolve[{CaputoD[y[x], {x, 3/2}] - Sqrt[y[x]] - y[2 x- 1] == 0, y[x /; x <= 0] == 2, y'[x /; x <= 0] == 1}, y[x], {x, a, b}]
```

How to change the code to work for range  $x\in \{-3,2\}$ and plot solution ?

Comment: This is fractional delayed differential equation FDDE since  we have  `y[2 x - 1]`. In a theory we need initial data for `x<0` as well to define function for `x>0`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev .Ok I update the code.

Comment: Initial data your given are not satisfier to equation.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Ok putt  some  random Initial data that satisfier to equation.

Comment: It means that you are looking for solution at `2>=x>0` only since at x<0 we define function with first derivative. Also please pay attention that in a new redaction you put   `y[x /; x <= 0] == 2, y'[x /; x <= 0] == 1` that is apparently wrong. :)

Comment: There are no mathematically proven methods to solve FDDE. Nevertheless we can try to use predictor corrector method described on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239669/could-anyone-please-suggest-me-mathematica-code-to-solve-fractional-order-time-d/239786#239786

Comment: @AlexTrounev .I tried with **Maple** with conditions: `y[x /; x <= 0] == 2, y'[x /; x <= 0] == 1` I got a correct
 numeric solution. Looks like initial conditions are OK.

Comment: For Maple maybe it is OK, but there is no function with $y'(x)=1$ and $y(x)=2$ at $x\le 0$. We can use $y'(x)=0, y(x)=2$, or $y'(x)=1,y(x)=x+2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fractional delayed differential equation (FDDE), therefore we can't use method described in my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271690/numerical-solution-for-a-non-linear-fractional-differential-equation-fde/271735?noredirect=1#comment736027_271735). Instead of the Haar wavelets method we try to use implicit difference scheme described in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s42967-019-00023-y). Note that for this type of equations we need to define $y(x)$ at $x\le 0$ and at $2x-1\ge a$ as well. Without this data we can't compute an unique solution. While for $x\le 0$ we have $y(x)=2, y'(x)=0$ (it could not be y'(x)=1 as given above), for $2x-1\ge 2$ we have no data. So, we put for example $f(2 x-1)=0, 2 x-1\ge 2$. To reduce the Caputo derivative order we introduce a new variable $z=y'(x)$, then our code is follows

```
L = 2; dx = L/100; xgrid = Range[0, L, dx]; nn = Length[xgrid];
M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
    DifferenceOrder -> 2]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
Z = Array[zz, {nn}]; Y = Array[yy, {nn}]; y0 = 2; dy0 = 0;
eq1 = Drop[Z - M1 . Y, 1]; bc = {Z[[1]] - dy0, Y[[1]] - y0};


a[j_][q_] := (j + 1)^(1 - q) - j^(1 - q);
b[j_][q_] := ((j + 1)^(2 - q) - j^(2 - q))/(2 - 
      q) - ((j + 1)^(1 - q) + j^(1 - q))/2;

eq2 = Table[0, {nn - 1}]; q = 1/2; Do[
 c[0] = If[n == 1, 1, a[0][q] + b[0][q]]; 
 If[n >= 2, 
  Do[c[j] = a[j][q] + b[j][q] - b[j - 1][q];, {j, 1, n - 2}]; 
  c[n - 1] = a[n - 1][q] - b[n - 2][q]]; 
 eq2[[n - 1]] = 
  dx^(-q)/Gamma[2 - q] (c[0] Z[[n]] - c[n - 1] Z[[1]] - 
      Sum[(c[n - j - 1] - c[n - j]) Z[[j]], {j, 1, n - 1}]) - 
   Sqrt[Y[[n]]] - 
   If[2 xgrid[[n]] - 1 <= 0, y0, 
    If[Round[(2 xgrid[[n]] - 1)/dx] >= nn + 1, 0, 
     Y[[Round[(2 xgrid[[n]] - 1)/dx]]]]];, {n, 2, nn}];

varALL = Join[Y, Z]; eqAll = Join[eq1, eq2, bc];
{res, {evx}} = 
  Reap[FindRoot[Table[eqAll[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqAll]}], 
    Table[{varALL[[i]], .1}, {i, Length[varALL]}], 
    Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"}, 
    MaxIterations -> 1000, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[varALL]]];
```

Visualization

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xgrid, Y /. res}], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: This wasn't what I expected. If I had a different equation, I would have to redo the entire code each time. Maybe it is possible to modify the code to be for general equation. and general initial conditions This **The paper** costs 39.95 euros quite expensive for me .Thanks positive answer (+1)

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Probably it is possible to modify code so that it could be applicable for general equation, but even for this simpler case we need some analysis to understand the function behavior.